# Website not being displayed correctly in Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, web-applications

I am given the task of fixing some defects in an ASP.NET web application. The first problem is that the web pages display properly on Google Chrome but when using IE the pages go all nuts, different parts overlapping and such. It cannot be fixed by compatibility view settings. I am totally new to .NET and C# so can somebody give me a clue as to where to look for the problem and from where to start fixing it? 
Furthermore, the site asks for authentication (i.e., username and password) when accessed through Firefox. Why does this happen in Firefox only?

Comment: It's probably using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Windows_Authentication in Internet Explorer. You'll need to look at the HTML and CSS, most likely. This is not going to be an easy task if you've zero webdev experience.

Comment: For the second question (assuming this is an intranet app), refer [this article](http://sanderstechnology.com/2011/configuring-firefox-to-allow-pass-through-authentication-ntlm/10594/#.VkvxFHYrLIU)

Comment: @ceejayoz Thank you very much. I have only a little bit of webdev experience but at least now I've got an idea from where to start. :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you. I changed it but Firfox still asks for authentication..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1.

Display problems with browsers are a **front-end** issue.

The **front-end** of a website is the bit that is rendered in a browser (a **client**). This includes HTML, CSS and Javascript. This is in contrast to the **back-end** which describes the server-side system (HTTP server, server-side code, database access etc). ASP.NET is a back-end technology.

Getting webpages to display correctly across many browsers and versions is actually quite difficult and a fairly large topic. My advice is to start small. Take little bits at a time and work on them until they display correctly in the browsers that you want to support.

Front-end is *what the user sees* and the back-end is *what the user doesn't see*.

## 2.

The second part of your question was answered by *ceejayoz* and *Stephen Muecke*. Basically, browsers can request your Windows credentials and most major browsers can be set up to automatically submit these credentials; otherwise you will be prompted for it.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is really helpful. :)

Answer (score -1):

To come out from design issue between the browser's, you can use `bootstrap` framework, that will auto care for design between the browser's not even for laptop and desktop, it will care for mobile and tab devices also.

```
Bootstrap is the greatest solution for any kind of design issue.
```

Comment: Bootstrap isn't technology, nor is it the "greatest solution" for anything, *particularly* fixing problems in an **existing** site. It's one of many CSS frameworks and is certainly useful in many cases, but not this one.

Comment: it was one of the solution to above question, If you are professional developer, So might you know, we can fix same issues with multiple ways, The same way I shared one of the solution.

Comment: OP is working on an *existing* application. Changing it to use Bootstrap would involve an extensive rewrite of the application's HTML and CSS.